# select 2 and flatpicker options are showing on top insted of below/above input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 jquery plugin but options are showing on top of page instead below input-
[example image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlsyX.png)

options code are added inside body instead of inside same parent as input element . I think that's why this is happening 
[preview](https://sanskul.com/student-details-form)

Comment: add you code here!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.